# Best way to benchmark Cassandra and Hbase for performance?

Tags: cassandra, hbase, benchmarking, nosql

What's the best way to benchmark Cassandra and Hbase for performance?

I'm working on an application where the Read (80%) and Write (20%) usage through an web application. Users can also do CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) to the data. Our data is all structured from (RDBMS). I have heard about YCSB (Yahoo! Cloud Serving Benchmark).

Had anyone done benchmark on Cassandra vs Hbase for a similar usecase like above?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your Cassandra is sitting behind a web app?

If so (as you mentioned CRUD), just benchmark the end points of your CRUD for WRITE (the Create) and the READ via Apache Workbench or Siege under load (ie concurrent calls, etc..)

**Update**

If you want to purely test if your configuration of Cassandra is correct for raw power:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress_t.html

but if you want to test the application as a whole, Apache workbench and Siege will test your App.

Comment: Hi @azngunit81- Thanks for the quick response. I have not heard about Workbench or Siege, let me take a look at it. But, more specifically I am trying to find out the best tool i.e. Cassandra vs HBase for my usecase here. So, I need to do a bench marking.

Comment: @RameshV I added a bit of extra.information on tools

Answer (score -1):

Most of the databases provide some tool to do performance testing. In my opinion, the best way to get an unbiased view is to use a third party tool like https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB which supports testing different types of ACID and NoSQL databases.